# Rip subtitles from DVD?

Tags: windows, software-rec, dvd, ripping, subtitles

What software (on windows) do I need (and what is best) to rip subtitles from DVD's, so they are stored in a separate file, that can be used with vobsub or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[SubRip](http://www.divx-digest.com/software/subrip.html)** is a nice little tool that allows you to convert imagemap-only subtitles that are on DVD discs into pure text format (which will take only couple of kilobytes of space after completed).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used [SubRip](http://zuggy.wz.cz/).